# Are Java Class objects unique / singletons?

Tags: java, class, singleton

are Class-objects guaranteed to be unique in the JVM, are they Singletons? i.e. will

```
getClass() == getClass()
```

always hold true and is

```
a == b
```

true if and only if

```
a.equals(b)
```

where a and b are of type `Class<?>`?

Comment: most definitely, class names are "optional"

Comment: Although this question may be a duplicate, I was able to reach it through Google even though I didn't reach the one this is a duplicate of, so I'm very glad this hasn't been deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have one singleton and/or class per class loader.

`a.equals(b)` is required to be true if `a == b` (except if a is `null`)